# My validation with true/false statements is not working properly

Tags: java

so i have a problem validating the last section of this code where i have commented

```
public void newTicket() throws Exception {
        boolean validation = false;

        boolean phoneUnique = false;
        int num;
        int member;
        String memberPhoneNum;
        final int memTicket = 80;
        final int nonMem = 100;
        int min = 100;
        int max = 200;
        int random_int = (int) Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
        int dd;
        int mm;
        int yy;
        String ticketDate;
        boolean isTrueDate = true;
        System.out.println();

        System.out.println("Transaction Id: " + random_int);
        int transactionId = random_int;

        do {
            System.out.print("Enter Day: ");
            dd = scan.nextInt();
            System.out.print("Enter Month");
            mm = scan.nextInt();
            System.out.print("Enter Year");
            yy = scan.nextInt();
            ticketDate = (dd + "" + mm + "" + yy);
            System.out.println("Ticket date: " + ticketDate);
            validation = v.checkDate(ticketDate);

            if (!isTrueDate) {
                System.out.println("Invalid"); // PROBLEM WITH VALIDATION
            }
        } while (!isTrueDate);
```

Whenever i enter a wrong date, for example: 300224, it still proceeds to the next line. ive tried changing the true/false statements but it still does work how i want it to.

```
public static boolean checkDate(String ticketDate) {

        boolean isTrueDate = true;
        int day = 0;
        int month = 0;
        int year = 0;
        if (month > 12) {
            isTrueDate = false;
        } else if (month == 1 || month == 3 || month == 5 || month == 7 || month == 8 || month == 10 || month == 12) {
            if (day <= 31) {
                isTrueDate = true;
            } else if (day >= 31) {
                isTrueDate = false;
            }
        } else if (month == 4 || month == 6 || month == 9 || month == 11) {
            if (day <= 30) {
                isTrueDate = true;
            } else if (day >= 30) {
                isTrueDate = false;
            }

        } else if (month == 2) // February check
        {
            if (year % 4 == 0) // Leap year check for February
            {
                if (day <= 29) {
                    isTrueDate = true;
                } else if (day >= 29) {
                    isTrueDate = false;
                }
            } else if (year % 4 != 0) {
                if (day <= 28) {
                    isTrueDate = true;
                } else if (day >= 28) {
                    isTrueDate = false;
                }
            }
        }
        return isTrueDate;
```

This is my validation class to test for leap years and whatnot

I appreciate any help given

Comment: Hello, try a debugger, It seems your `year`, `month` and `day` variables inside the validator are always `0`.

Comment: Your newTicket method never changes the value of `isTrueDate`.

Answer (score 0):

I am new to this site too, but I can try to give you a response that may help.
This is going to be a long one, as I have a lot of potential issues to solve. I will provide something that I think could work at the end though.

The first thing I noticed is that your long series of conditionals involves a lot of brackets and you may have missed one as you nested many of them into each other. I did a thorough check and really, the only one I did not see was the one that should end the boolean method after `return isTrueDate;` so I thought I should mention it just in case. To be clear, you probably have it, but make sure you have a bracket that closes the method. Also in the future, make sure to put the whole code snippet for clarity. Thanks in advance.

Now the second thing I see is the way you got the validation. I do not know exactly what you mean when you say `validation = v.checkDate(ticketDate);` in the first code snippet because I do not know what v is, although I will assume it is the main class. In this case, while I am not sure, it looks like you are trying to run your method and assign the boolean value of whether the date is a real date to the value of validation. This makes sense, but what I think you should change is how you used `isTrueDate` to verify by asking if the value is not `isTrueDate`. I think it might solve an issue if you simply put an invalid response on `validation` being false and vice versa for `validation` being true. Here's an example:

```
    validation = v.checkDate(ticketDate);
    if (validation == true) {
      //Something here if you want.
      //However you may not need this space.
    } else {
      System.out.println("invalid")
    }
```

However, with this, there are really two approaches that I can think of: the one that preserves security and the one that ensures your code is working.
So the code above is better at preserving security b/c it accounts for anything that may not make the validation false in the else statement in addition to it being false because your code worked properly. For example, if your series of conditionals has a flaw in it, b/c you initialized validation as being false, if something goes wrong, its likely to just invalidate the ticket, which could be semi-useful in a security sense to avoid some vulnerabilities. However, you can do that later. The first thing you need to make sure of is that your code works properly, so I would also recommend that when you declare validate at the top of your first code snippet, to not initialize it.

Like this:

```
boolean validation;
```

Instead of this:

```
boolean validation = false;
```

This ensures that your series of conditionals is responsible for the value of `validation` rather than the conditions simply not working and the value being false by default.

This brings me to another thing that I believe would also cause problems in your code.
It refers to this section from your first code snippet:

```
    boolean isTrueDate = true;
    System.out.println();

    System.out.println("Transaction Id: " + random_int);
    int transactionId = random_int;
```

So two things:

- The easy one refers to the bottom two lines. It's not a mistake causing you errors, but I would suggest switching the order of the bottom two lines to assign `transactionId` to the value of `random_int` and then printing:

  System.out.println("Transaction Id: " + transactionId);
- Now the second one is the real problem. In the code above you are assigning true to `isTrueDate`.
  This is a problem because you are later using `isTrueDate` in that series of conditionals in that other boolean method called `checkDate()`
  This will mess up your code. Here is how:
- So first the `isTrueDate` you used inside your method, `checkDate()` is kept local to that method because you declared it inside there. If you did not do this, you likely would have gotten a separate error because you declared a boolean `isTrueDate` in two separate places. You declared it at the top in that first code snippet, and you declared it in that method. Normally, this would cause an error because you have already declared it once and changing the value would only require you to assign `isTrueDate` to something else with an equal sign rather than declaring it again. To really show you what I mean, look at this example:

Incorrect:

```
boolean isTrueDate = true;
//Other actions
//I want to change the value of isTrueDate
boolean isTrueDate = false;
```

Correct:

```
boolean isTrueDate = true;
//Other actions
//I want to change the value of isTrueDate
isTrueDate = false;
```

What you did (doesn't return error but messes up your code):
I put it in a different order to better show the problem.

```
public static boolean checkDate(String ticketDate) {
    boolean isTrueDate = true; //first declaration

//Lots of conditions
}
static void someMethod() {

//This method may not be exactly how you did it, 
//but you did not show me that.

    boolean isTrueDate = true; //usually invalid second declaration. 
    //However, it still works b/c they are in different methods and
    // thus kept separate from each other. This still messes up your
    // code though

    //more code
    validation = v.checkDate(ticketDate);
    if (!isTrueDate) {
      System.out.println("Invalid");
    }
      //Doesn't work b/c the value of isTrueDate you initialized
      // in someMethod() is the one that this if else statement checks 
      // instead of the one that you used in checkDate()
      //That means, isTrueDate will always be true.

    //To solve this, you must first use validation to present the
    // invalid message as discussed above, but furthermore, you should
    // delete the initialization of isTrueDate in the method that is
    // not checkDate() because you don't need it there. 
}
```

Sorry, that's a lot to explain, and there may be more to fix, but I have one more correction for now: I looked through the conditionals that you used to account for all the ways a date could be correct or incorrect and I think its pretty good for the most part, but I can offer one thing that will save you some lines.
Every time you check if a date is within the max number of days for that month, you then put a separate `else if` condition that accounts for the other of the two possibilities. Here's an example from your code:

```
if (day <= 31) {
    isTrueDate = true;
} else if (day >= 31) {
    isTrueDate = false;
}
```

This does help to show exactly what is happening, but I would still advise deleting this `else if` part and replacing it with one big `else {}` part at the end because it would say the same thing as all of these other separate `else if` blocks, just much more concisely. Here is what that would look like:

```
//This new list of conditions will work such that it finds every true
// possibility and denies everything else.

if (month < 12) //Changed to fit new strategy
{
    if (month == 1 || month == 3 || month == 5 || month == 7 || month == 8 || month == 10 || month == 12)
    {
        if (day <= 31)
        {
            isTrueDate = true;
        }

    } else if (month == 4 || month == 6 || month == 9 || month == 11) 
    {
        if (day <= 30)
        {
            isTrueDate = true;
        }

    } else if (month == 2) // February check
    {
        if (year % 4 == 0) // Leap year check for February
        {
            if (day <= 29)
            {
                isTrueDate = true;
            }
        } else if (year % 4 != 0)
        {
            if (day <= 28)
            {
                isTrueDate = true;
            }
        }
    }
} else { // All the times it was false
        isTrueDate = false;
}

return isTrueDate;
```

So there you have it. As thorough as I could because in truth, this is my first answered question and I wanted to do it right. I hope it helps in some way. The main thing is to make sure that the data you received from the scanner correctly enters into the method and that the right data from that method goes to your validation. I'll leave you with everything I can think to correct on both snippets.

New Snippet 1:

```
public void newTicket() throws Exception {
    boolean validation;

    boolean phoneUnique = false;
    int num;
    int member;
    String memberPhoneNum;
    final int memTicket = 80;
    final int nonMem = 100;
    int min = 100;
    int max = 200;
    int random_int = (int) Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
    int dd;
    int mm;
    int yy;
    String ticketDate;
    //Removed unnecessary declaration of isTrueDate in this part
    System.out.println(); //I don't know why you have this but I will leave it alone.

    int transactionId = random_int; //Switched
    System.out.println("Transaction Id: " + transactionId);
    

    do { // I like this part
        System.out.print("Enter Day: ");
        dd = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Enter Month");
        mm = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Enter Year");
        yy = scan.nextInt();
        ticketDate = (dd + "" + mm + "" + yy);
        System.out.println("Ticket date: " + ticketDate);
        validation = v.checkDate(dd, mm, yy); //This change is explained in snippet 2

        if (validation == false) { //uses validation instead of isTrueDate
            System.out.println("Invalid"); // Hopefully this helps
        }
    } while (!isTrueDate); //I don't know what happens here so I won't touch.
     //Code that was not shown
```

New Snippet 2:

```
//parameters changed
public static boolean checkDate(int day, int month, int year) {

    boolean isTrueDate; //Changed out of preference
    //int day = 0;
    //int month = 0; No longer needed in this new code.
    //int year = 0;
    //One more problem:
    //It looks like you tried to use ticketDate as the parameter
    // to get the values for days, month, and year, but this
    // doesn't quite work b/c there is not anything that takes that 
    // string and then extracts the values for day, month and year.

    //The way I chose to address this was by placing the day, month,
    // and year as parameters in the checkDate() method, and then
    // calling checkDate() in snippet one with the values of the
    // scanner. 
    //However, there are other ways to do this. For example, you could
    // keep your ticketDate String and then access different parts of
    // that String to get the values of day, month, and year.
    //In the end, I just did what seemed easiest to me.

//This new list of conditions will work such that it finds every true
// possibility and denies everything else.

    if (month < 12) //Changed to fit new strategy
    {
        if (month == 1 || month == 3 || month == 5 || month == 7 || month == 8 || month == 10 || month == 12)
        {
            if (day <= 31)
            {
                isTrueDate = true;
            }

        } else if (month == 4 || month == 6 || month == 9 || month == 11) 
        {
            if (day <= 30)
            {
                isTrueDate = true;
            }

        } else if (month == 2) // February check
        {
            if (year % 4 == 0) // Leap year check for February
            {
                if (day <= 29)
                {
                    isTrueDate = true;
                }
            } else if (year % 4 != 0)
            {
                if (day <= 28)
                {
                    isTrueDate = true;
                }
            }
        }
    } else { // All the times it was false
        isTrueDate = false;
    }

    return isTrueDate;

} //The extra bracket! Closes the method
```

Peace <3